# Django: Cannot download generating file

Tags: python, django, download, django-templates, httpresponse

I am trying to generate a text file and download it from link in the template but nothing happen after I click a link.

This is my link in template.

```
<a href="{% url 'download' %}"><h2>{{ fname }} {{ lname }}</h2></a>
```

And this is my views

```
def report_generate(request):
    f = open("test.txt", "w+")
    for i in range(10):
        f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i + 1))

    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='text/plain')
    filename = "guru99.txt"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
    return response
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', qrview.index),
path('forms/new_profile', formsview.profile_create, name="aaa"),    # test
path('forms/new_course', formsview.course_create, name="ddd"),      # test
path('forms/edit_course', formsview.course_edit, name="edit_course"),   
path('report/', reportview.report, name="report"),
path('report/', reportview.report_generate, name="download"),
#path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
#path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

Comment: Any response or error ?

Comment: No error and no response after I click the link.

Comment: I don't even see download dialog.

Comment: How are you linked the template and view?

Comment: Oh, I already solve my problem. It seem my link have some error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your case `f.read()` is returning an empty string, you have to manually move the file pointer at the beginning of the file in order to read the content after writing

```
def report_generate(request):
  f = open("test.txt", "w+")
  for i in range(10):
    f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i + 1))
  f.seek(0) # Move the pointer at the beginning
  response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='text/plain')
  f.close() # Close the file
  filename = "guru99.txt"
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
  return response
```

Comment: Still not solve my problem, I'm still not see download dialog.

Comment: Thank so much, your answer help me to solve the problem that no text in file.

Answer (score 0):

**urls.py**

```
  url(r'^(?P<filename>(test.txt))$',
    home_files, name='home-files')
```

**views.py**

```
def server_text_file(request, filename):
    return render(request, filename, {}, content_type="text/plain")
```

and you test.txt file in `templates` folder and you will be able to get the file.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. It seems like my urls.py have some error because of name.

Before I fixes it, reportview.report and reportview.report_generate have same route.

```
path('report/', reportview.report, name="report"),
path('report/', reportview.report_generate, name="download"),
```

This is new urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', qrview.index),
path('forms/new_profile', formsview.profile_create, name="aaa"),    # test
path('forms/new_course', formsview.course_create, name="ddd"),      # test
path('forms/edit_course', formsview.course_edit, name="edit_course"),   # test
path('report/', reportview.report, name="report"),
path('report/download', reportview.report_generate, name="download"),
```

]

Even now I'm still confuse what actually happen? I think that when I click link It will go to code in reportview.report_generate and generate text file and download it.